# Quarkus and Ibm Mq integration

Tags: ibm-mq, quarkus

i'm totally new to quarkus and i'm trying to figure out a way to integrate and connect to an ibm mq queue. My goal is to basically have a sender which send some string messages to a queue (with a scheduler to send a message every x seconds) and a recevier which listen on the queue and log the message received on the queue. Is there any way to achieve so?

I've tried to research for some examples however i was unable to find anything. I tried to use an emitter object signed with the @Channel annotation to send messages and to annotate a method with the @Incoming annotation on the receiver, but I don't know if this is the right approach.

Thanks a lot for your support

Comment: You can try using the [Smallrye MQTT connector (`smallrye.io`)](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-reactive-messaging/smallrye-reactive-messaging/3.3/mqtt/mqtt.html). This connnector, however, is not native-compatible. I know of no native-compatible connector for IBM MQ.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but you will need to use the QPID AMQP stack, and switch on AMQP. See the tutorial at https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/mq-running-ibm-mq-apps-on-quarkus-and-graalvm-using-qpid-amqp-jms-classes/